# select rows from multi tables sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

if  I have multi table with same columns in SQL

table_A

```
No  date       data     Col_A
1   1/1/2011    a_1     a
```

table_B

```
No  date        data    Col_B
1   1/1/2014    b_1      b
2   1/1/2014    b_1      b
```

table_C

```
 No date       data     Col_C
 1  5/2/2014    c_1      c
```

what is the sql command to get the result from three table where (No = 1) like this

```
table_name  No  date    data
table_A     1   1/1/2011    a_1
table_B     1   1/1/2014    b_1
table_C     1   5/2/2014    c_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is union all:

```
select 'table_A' as table_name, No, date, data from table_A
where No = 1
union all
select 'table_B', No, date, data from table_B
where No = 1
union all
select 'table_C', No, date, data from table_C
where No = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `union all` operator, and have the table name as a string literal

```
SELECT 'table_A' AS table_name, [No], [date], [Col_A] AS data
FROM   table_A
WHERE  [No] = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table_B' AS table_name, [No], [date], [Col_B] AS data
FROM   table_B
WHERE  [No] = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table_C' AS table_name, [No], [date], [Col_C] AS data
FROM   table_C
WHERE  [No] = 1
```

EDIT:
Note that the alias on the second and third queries are inconsequential, but I added them for readability's sake.